# Как после выполнения операторов DML получить все затронутые записи?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть ли в PLS/QL команды/функции, которые после выполнения операторов DML перед `commit` могли бы показать записи с уже обновленными, добавленными или удаленными данными?

Примерно [что-то такое](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68acdc694b2b4e7fac0a23dc56a5ec90):

```
create table t as
with cte as (
     select 1 woid,'abc' words from dual union all
     select 2 woid,'abc1' words from dual
) select * from cte;

--обновляем, добавляем или удаляем записи в таблице 
update t 
    set words = 'qwe'
where <какое-то условие>; 

select * from t where <какое-то условие>;

--после проверки коммит
commit;
```

Запросом перед `commit` можно, например, получить обновленные записи. Но как получить все затронутые записи после выполнения любых операторов DML? Ведь удалённые записи уже запросом не получить, а для добавленных - неизвестны их ID после вставки.

Comment: При выполнении - нет, после выполнения можно что-то сделать. Покажите в вопросе, хоть псевдо-кодом, что вы делаете и каков ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Сначала обновляем таблицу (cte), затем выводи то, что получилось (записал рез-тат в cte2), коммитим (скрипт в саму задачу приложил)

Comment: Адаптировал ваш псевдокод [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=182d8784840af454b820a7cf1a3373e3). Посмотрите, что там не соответствует вашей бизнес логике. Исправте, дополните, напишите комментарий и опубликуйте новую ссылку (код по ссылке не обязательно должен быть рабочим).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспроизводимый и наглядный пример для реализации ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a4820709b3fe66eb40cf3470110cfbe)):

```
select * from t;

      WOID WOR
---------- ---
         1 abc
         2 def

declare 
    type trows is table of t%rowtype;
    rows trows; 
    totalrows trows := trows ();
    rowcount int := 0;
begin
    update t set words='qwe' where woid=1
    returning woid, words bulk collect into rows;   
    rowcount := rowcount + sql%rowcount; 
    totalrows := totalrows multiset union rows;
    
    delete from t where woid=2
    returning woid, words bulk collect into rows;
    rowcount := rowcount + sql%rowcount; 
    totalrows := totalrows multiset union rows;

    dbms_output.put_line ('totalrows/rowcount='||totalrows.count||'/'||rowcount); 
    if (rowcount = totalrows.count) then 
        dbms_output.put_line ( -- любые проверки вместо вывода 
            'updated row(1)='||totalrows(1).words||chr(10)||
            'deleted row(2)='||totalrows(2).words);
        -- вернуть ок, вызывающий сделает commit    
    else
        raise_application_error (-20000, 'error: totalrows not еqual rowcount');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Вывод:

```
totalrows/rowcount=2/2
updated row(1)=qwe
deleted row(2)=def
```